# Passing a class ("Country.class") as an argument in Java

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to make a method that takes an argument of `Country.class`, `User.class` etc, and returns `argument.count()`.

All the possible classes that I would give to this method extend from `Model` and have the method `count()`.

**My code:**

```
private static long <T> countModel(Model<T> clazz)
{
    // there is other important stuff here, which prevents me from
    // simply by-passing the method altogether.

    return clazz.count();
}
```

**Called by:**

```
renderArgs.put("countryCount", countModel(Country.class));
```

However this just doesn't work at all.

How do I do this, please?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for, `Country.class` is a `Class` and doesn't have any `count()`. Could you rephrase your question in plain english?

Comment: You are excepting classes to have a specific static method? That's an extremely strange design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
private long countModel(Class<? extends Model> clazz) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
{
  Method countMethod =  clazz.getDeclaredMethod("count", null);
  return (Long) countMethod.invoke(null, null);
}
```

Hopefully something like this would work (my reflection skills are not really that good).

Comment: This is it! Just needed to take out the "null" arguments and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Did you mean this?

```
private static long <T> countModel(Model<T> model)
{
    return model.count();
}

renderArgs.put("countryCount", countModel(country));
```

EDIT: If count is a static method, it has nothing to do with model. The static method is not inherited. So all you have to do is to call it directly,

```
renderArgs.put("countryCount", Country.count());
```

Comment: No, the classes have `count()` as a static method, not the objects. Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: The first part doesn't even compile so I don't think that this is what the OP meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Clarifying, you want a class (`A`) that is constrained to have a particular class method (`B`) and you want to pass that class as an argument to some other method (`C`) and have that method (C) invoke that class method on that class (`A.B()`)?

The first part, the type constraint, that can't be done. Java's type system just does not work that way.

The second part, passing a class as an argument and invoking a class method on it, that *can* be done using reflection. This is how to do it, correcting from your code (though you should be more careful with the exceptions than I've been in this).

```
private static <T extends Model> long countModel(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception
{
    return (Long) clazz.getMethod("count").invoke(null);
}
```

The `null` is the instance to invoke this on (no instance; it's a class method). The cast to `Long` is required as the result of `invoke()` is an `Object`. The type parameter must go before the result type. And the whole thing can take *any* class that is a subclass of `Model` as a parameter; it will just fail at runtime if the `count` method isn't present. Them's the breaks.

(Also note that if you wanted to pass arguments to `count()`, you'd have to specify the classes of those arguments to `getMethod` and the values themselves to `invoke`, in both cases as subsequent arguments. Both support Java5 variable argument lists.)

Comment: Thanks, this works. frosty_hotboy was first so I gave him the tick.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
renderArgs.put("countryCount", countModel(Country.class));
```

you call `countModel` with a `Class<Country>`, but you have to call it with an instance of `Country` like this:

```
Country country = new Country();
renderArgs.put("countryCount", countModel( country );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing an instance of country here, you are passing a Class object:

```
renderArgs.put("countryCount", countModel(Country.class));
```

You need to instantiate A model and pass it as an argument:

```
Model model = new Country();
renderArgs.put("countryCount", countModel(model));
```

or

```
Country country = new Country();
renderArgs.put("countryCount", countModel(country));
```

In this case, `Country.class` is an object of the `Class<Country>` type.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your comment to ZZ Coder; a static method in Java is called in the namespace context of a class, like `Model.count()` for a static method `count()` in the class `Model`, but the method does not become part of `Model.class`, `Model.class` is an instance of `Class` describing the class `Model`. (I can see where the confusion originates, it would be logical to have a specialised `Model.class` that includes the static methods, but Java isn't desinged that way.)

Your way out is to use reflection to call the static `count()` for the class that you pass to your code.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing `Country.class` which is a `Class` object. How is it a `Model` object?