# Passing "Class.class" to a function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a class (“Country.class”) as an argument in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889588/passing-a-class-country-class-as-an-argument-in-java)

I am trying to write a generic save function for Amazon Web Service's DynamoDB.

Currently I have:

```
public void save(????? classType, AmazonDynamoDBItem item)
{
    try
    {
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(_dynamoDB);
        ????? object = mapper.load(classType, item.getKey());
        mapper.save(object);
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to make a signature that can accept something like (for exmple) `String.class`.

What do I need to put into the `?????` to make this function work?

Comment: Well, what does the javadoc say `String.getClass()` returns?

Comment: The Class class should be it:
public void save(Class classType, AmazonDynamoDBItem item){
   Class object = mapper.load(classType, item.getKey());
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static <E> void save(Class<E> classType)
{
    try {
        E object = classType.newInstance();
        System.out.println(object.getClass());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `classType` parameter must be of type `Class<?>`, i.e. any `Class` object.

Comment: What would the syntax be to create a class of that type inside of the function?  `classType variable = new classType();` doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to create a new instance yourself, then @AKJ's answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to write a generic save function

Then use [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Generic functions allow you to pass in a type as a "parameter", but it doesn't occur in the argument list.  In your case, you want something like:

```
// The "T" is the type you want to pass
public <T> void save(AmazonDynamoDBItem item)
{
    try
    {
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(_dynamoDB);
        T object = mapper.load<T>(item.getKey());
        mapper.save(object);
    }
    ...
}
```

Your `load` function has to be similarly programmed to accept generic types.

Comment: Wrong. Generic type info is erased at runtime.  In your sample, what is `classType`?  You MUST pass the class to the `mapper.load` method, and since you can't get the type parameter at runtime a `Class` object is needed.

Comment: Then I misunderstood his question.  I wasn't familiar with AWS and I thought DynamoDBMapper was a class he created that he could define the behavior of at compile time.  Without that knowledge, I thought it was curious that he would need a type parameter after compile time.